# Ping a lot of IPs

Tags: vb.net

For like 10 IPS there isnt a problem . But when i try to ping 200 Ips it lags the UI for 5 secs and the cpu usage goes very high . Is there any other way of doing this?

```
          Dim obj As New Object
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        Dim T As New Thread(Sub()
                                Thread.Sleep(10)
                                Dim p As Ping
                                Dim reply As PingReply
                                p = New Ping
                                reply = p.Send(item.Text)
                                SyncLock obj
                                               list.Add(reply.RoundtripTime.ToString)
                                End SyncLock
                            End Sub)
        T.Start()
    Next
```

Comment: Instead of creating your own threads, call `Ping.SendAsync` and let the `ThreadPool` manage the threads.  That should keep the CPU usage down a bit.  It will make your code a bit more complex, because you will need to handle events and possibly track which IP address the event is for (although you're not tracking which address a response is for now) but it will perform better.

Comment: In order to prevent freezing while you initiate all the operations, you may need to do it from an asynchronous method of some sort, e.g. using a `Task` or the `DoWork` event of a `backgroundWorker`.

Comment: You can't access `item` inside your thread code. Firstly it's a UI element and secondly the loop would have finished before the threads start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `item` inside your thread code. Firstly it's a UI element and access UI elements from a non-UI thread is bad. Secondly the loop would iterated through many, if not all, of the elements before the first thread starts meaning that the `item` inside the thread will have changed before the thread starts.

You're also not disposing your `Ping` object. That's a memory leak.

You're best off using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. It makes this super easy. Just do this:

```
Dim subscription As IDisposable =
    ListView1 _
        .Items _
        .Cast(Of ListViewItem) _
        .Select(Function (lvi) lvi.Text) _
        .ToObservable() _
        .SelectMany(Function (t) Observable.Using( _
            Function () New Ping(), _
            Function (p) Observable.Start(Function () p.Send(t).RoundtripTime.ToString()))) _
        .ToList() _
        .ObserveOn(ListView1) _
        .Subscribe( _
            Sub (list)
                ' Do something with your list here
            End Sub)
```

This correctly accesses the UI elements before any threading takes place. It disposes of your `Ping` instances. It marshalls back to the UI thread. It finally returns your list in the `.Subscribe` method for you to do with as you need to.

Just NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and then add a `Imports System.Reactive` to your code.